# Node modules on network driver

Tags: angular, node-modules, network-drive

I'm trying to have all of the node modules placed in a network driver, so me and my teammates can share them to all our angular projects(since moving node modules takes a tremendous amount of time, which can be avoided with this solution).

I've already added the node modules to our existing network driver which we all share and have access to, and pointed the path of our projects to that path.
The problem is with the compilation- each compilation of the code in vs code, takes a lot of time(several minutes instead of seconds). 
Is there any reason it does that or any better way to get the desired behavior by doing something else perhaps?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is really non-recommend.

`/node_modules` is a big folder and you don't wane overheat your network right ?

The correct is sharing just the `package.json` and work with npm separately on local machines. Because of this node_modules is automatically writed at .gitignore when you start angular project.

Comment: node_modules have hundreds of folders inside, on angular build this folder is readed, if all team use the same folder on a network drive the traffic will increase.

Comment: what do you mean by overheating the network,why would it happen? (will it happen also if the network is local?)Also, if i still need it to be in a network driver as a demand- any way to reduce the amount of time of the compilation? And lastly, if i share the package.json, it still requires to me have the node modules at everyone's pc and when something updates,to update it for everyone else aswell.